# Why am I getting an "index out of range" error when base64 encoding a byte array?

Tags: arrays, go, base64

When encoding a byte array into a base64 byte array, the below code produces a runtime `index out of range` error. How can this be resolved?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "encoding/base64"
)

func main() {
    data := []byte("string of data")
    var encodedData []byte
    base64.StdEncoding.Encode(encodedData, data)
    fmt.Println(encodedData)
}
```

[Playground here](https://play.golang.org/p/W5uLpFVWBy)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The error is:

```
panic: runtime error: index out of range

goroutine 1 [running]:
encoding/base64.(*Encoding).Encode(0xc420056000, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0xc42003bf30, 0xe, 0x20)
        /usr/lib/go/src/encoding/base64/base64.go:113 +0x27b
main.main()
        /home/martin/a.go:11 +0x9b
exit status 2

shell returned 1
```

If we look at `/usr/lib/go/src/encoding/base64/base64.go` line 113, we see (abbreviated):

```
n := (len(src) / 3) * 3
for si < n {
    // [..]
    dst[di+0] = enc.encode[val>>18&0x3F]
    dst[di+0] = enc.encode[val>>18&0x3F]
    dst[di+1] = enc.encode[val>>12&0x3F]
    // [..]
}
```

In other words, this function *directly* sets the index of `dst`. The length of `var encodedData []byte` is zero, so you get the `index out of range` error.

One way to fix it would be to change the line to:

```
encodedData := make([]byte, base64.StdEncoding.EncodedLen(len(data)))
```

Which will make an array of the size in the second argument. Base64 encoded data is larger than the input, hence the `base64.StdEncoding.EncodedLen()`.

However, this is hardly the best way to fix it. [The documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/base64/#Encoding.Encode) mentions:

> Encode is not appropriate for use on individual blocks of a large data stream. Use NewEncoder() instead.

Rewriting the code to `NewEncoder()` looks like:

```
func main() {
    data := []byte("string of data")

    encodedData := &bytes.Buffer{}
    encoder := base64.NewEncoder(base64.StdEncoding, encodedData)
    defer encoder.Close()
    encoder.Write(data)

    fmt.Println(encodedData)
}
```

There also some other useful functions, such as `EncodeToString()` which make the above a bit shorter and more convenient: `encodedData  := base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString(data)`.

Comment: Thanks for the in-depth answer! How would the encoded data then be decoded?

Comment: I'm confident you can find the answer to that question [in the documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/base64/) @jscionti :-)

Answer (score 4):

Allocate space for the output. For example,

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/base64"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    data := []byte("string of data")
    encodedData := make([]byte, base64.StdEncoding.EncodedLen(len(data)))
    base64.StdEncoding.Encode(encodedData, data)
    fmt.Println(encodedData)
}
```

Output:

```
[99 51 82 121 97 87 53 110 73 71 57 109 73 71 82 104 100 71 69 61]
```

`var encodedData []byte` is zero bytes. Therefore, `index out of range`

Answer (score 1):

Because [Encode](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/base64/#Encoding.Encode) expects the `dst` slice to be allocated to the correct length.

> Encode encodes src using the encoding enc, writing
>   EncodedLen(len(src)) bytes to dst.